# Who are these villains in the Injustice movie?

Tags: dc, character-identification, injustice, injustice-2021

In the DC animated movie when Wonder woman goes to catch Mirror Master she goes to a bar "The World's End" where so many villains were present. Who are these villains shown in the pictures below?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First image (from left to right)**

- [Killer Frost (Louise Lincoln)](https://injustice.fandom.com/wiki/Killer_Frost)
- [Trickster (Axel Walker)](https://injustice.fandom.com/wiki/Trickster)
- [Giganta (Doris Zuel)](https://injustice.fandom.com/wiki/Giganta)
- [Captain Boomerang (George Harkness)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/George_Harkness_(Injustice))
- [Catman (Thomas Blake)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Thomas_Blake_(New_Earth))

**Second image (from left to right)**

- [Catman (Thomas Blake)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Thomas_Blake_(New_Earth))
- [Pied Piper (Hartley Rathaway)](https://injustice.fandom.com/wiki/Pied_Piper)
- [Plastique (Bette Sans Souci)](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Plastique)
- [Captain Cold (Leonard Snart)](https://injustice.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Cold)

**Third image (from left to right)**

- [Enchantress](https://injustice.fandom.com/wiki/Enchantress)
- [Mantis](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Mantis_(New_Earth))
- [Mirror Master (Evan McCulloch)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Evan_McCulloch_(Injustice))
- [Weather Wizard (Mark Mardon)](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Weather_Wizard)

I'm a little unsure about Pied Piper (Hartley Rathaway), as we only see that character from behind, and he also bears a resemblance to [Doctor Alchemy (Albert Desmond)](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Alchemy).